# http request with Fuel

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to do HTTP request with Fuel library in Android kotlin and I want to request Synchronously. But I can't get data with the below code. Does anyone know why? or Fuel library don't have sync functionality?

```
val hoge = "https://xxxxx.com/id/1".httpGet().response()
println(String(hoge.third.component1()))
```

Comment: https://ryanharrison.co.uk/2018/06/15/make-http-requests-kotlin.html

Comment: Do you get any errors? Android should block any network request fired on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

Fuel can perform a request in synchronized way. Your code is perfectly fine and it works for me. 
Make sure your server works fine and in case you are on android that you have added necessary permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Apart from this, your code can be improved. Notice that `response()` method of `Request` class will get you `ByteArray`. If you need string you should use:

```
"https://xxxxx.com/id/1".httpGet().responseString()
println(hoge.third.component1())
```

The newest version of Fuel library allows you to do it in even better way using kotlin coroutines. You can mark your function as suspend and call `awaitString()`. The thread will be blocked until you get the response.

```
"https://xxxxx.com/id/1".httpGet().awaitString()
println(hoge)
```